# Neo4j Driver can't connect to server becouse of security constraints in Firefox browser

Tags: firefox, neo4j

I create the same project as in [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-1A7f8993M) but my project do not display anything.

I create new sandbox as in movie on this platform neo4jsandbox.com

I copied the IP and port correctly.

after many tries, I add

```
console.log(viz);
```

and this is what I get:

`` Neo4jError: "WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3" ``

What should I change to make it possible to connect to this server?

Btw. I create the local neo4j server and the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

The Neo4j browser tries to establish a secure connection with the bolt protocol through port 7687. There is a self-signed SSL certificate that Firefox does not accept. The connection to 7686 is opened in the background so you do not get a warning.

Go to the following URL in a new Firefox tab:

`https://same-host-as-before:7687`

Firefox will warn you that there is an untrusted/self-signed certificate. Allow this and continue.

Now you can go to the Neo4j browser again and you should be able to connect. Reload the page to make sure you reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter `https:yourhost:7354` into the Foxfire address bar, it transforms the URL in the Neo4j browser to `bolt://yourhost:7687` and this does not work in Firefox. If you change the Neo4j browser back to `https:yourhost:7354` and enter your password, it will login and display the Neo4j database.

I don't know why Firefox will not accept the bolt protocol. Perhaps someone else does?